# Depending on type of AJAX request show LoadingGif

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have 1 POST ajax and 1 GET ajax, and I have this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            $("#div28").show();
        });
        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            $("#div28").hide();
        });

    });
```

It is for showing the LoadingGif, at this point it is showing for both Ajax requests, so what should I do to make the LoadingGif show only when the POST type ajax is working?

**EDIT:**
Here are my ajax functions:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'api/Appointments/', 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if ((result.AppTime = "9:00") && (result.AppWithYritys = "Laakkonen")) {
                    document.getElementById("A9").style.background = "red";
                }
                else {
                    alert("error1");
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("error");
            },
        });
    });
```

and the POST ajax:

```
  var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(app),
            url: "/api/Appointments",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "html"
        });

        request.done(function (data) {
            if (data != -1) {
                alert("You Have successfully made an appointment");
                location.assign("http://tid.fi");
            }
            else {
                alert("There has been an error!");
            }
        });

        request.fail(function (gr) {
            location.assign("http://google.com");
        });
    };
```

POST ajax is in a custom function which is trigger on a button-click. Just an info.

Comment: Can you show the Ajax implementation of your calls, i do not think this goes in your $(document).ready function.

Comment: try using [ajaxSend](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/)

Comment: @ergwin sure, give me a minute.

Comment: probably the easiest thing to do would be to just set a page `var` e.g. `var ajaxType = 'post'` and set that on the function call

Comment: place it in `show(ajaxType)` and `hide(ajaxType)`?
@Eonasdan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `ajaxSend` and `ajaxComplete` you can see what the "type" of request is

However, you'll need to keep a count of active requests too - possibly not required for your simple page - but it's good to have

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var started = 0;
    $(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jqXHR, settings) {
        if (settings.type == 'POST') {
            if(!(started++)) { // only need to show on the first simultaneous POST
                $("#div28").show();
            }
        }
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, jqXHR, settings) {
        if (settings.type == 'POST') {
            if(!(--started)) { // only hide once all simultaneous POST have completed
                $("#div28").hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Solution without counters

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jqXHR, settings) {
        if (settings.type == 'POST') {
            $("#div28").show();
        }
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $("#div28").hide();
    });
});
```

This will show on POST, and hide once all ajax has stopped - a little less obvious, but it's probably just as valid a solution

Comment: Pretty cool, although i am not convinced with using counters for this. :)

Comment: well, if you KNOW you'll only ever have a single POST request in flight, then sure, you don't need the "inner" if statements

Comment: no actually I will probably have multiple requests, because it is an appointments booking website, so this is good. The answer is good also, exact and precise... Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I've added a solution without the need for a counter

Comment: but what is the counters role in all of this?

Comment: `I will probably have multiple requests, because it is an appointments booking website` - not sure how an appointments booking website implies that there would be *multiple in flight per session*

Comment: Now I'm confused, I thought You meant that if there is gonna be a lot of POST requests then a counter is needed?
what is this multiple in flight session?

Comment: The counter is there to only trigger `show` when the first (of multiple simultaneous in-flight) POST requests is made, and trigger `hide` when the last (of multiple simultaneous in-flight) POST requests is complete - however - it's probably overkill - the second code snippet should work just as well

Comment: Ajax is asyncrhonous ... you can start a request while another one is "still going" (I used the term in-flight) ... the counter is needed in the first example because if you have START, START, COMPLETE, COMPLETE, the div needs to hide after the SECOND complete - really, the second code is fine, forget about the first code

Comment: Oh, I get it now, didn't understand You, sorry for my stupid questions, I'm still learning Ajax  :/ I guess in my scenario I will have one post then, so the second code will be fine

Comment: It's all good - as I said, second solution is probably better - the first solution would be appropriate if you needed to display how many requests are in progress for example

Comment: Got it! Tnx for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest option is to create a tiny functions that you can use:

```
function showLoading(isLoading){
      if(isLoading){
      $("#div28").show();
  }
  else{
      $("#div28").hide();
  }
};
```

Then use as documented here [Ajax events](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

just use the function either using the global events for your specific post or call the function directly on the `beforeSend` and `complete` event hooks.

Comment: How does this distinguish between POST and GET?

Comment: If you have a better way , you may go ahead and propose the solution. I would just call the function directly from the ajax method.